# How to read image from URL (urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden)

Tags: python, http, https, urllib, http-status-code-403

I have a code that returns an image (API) :

url1 = "https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/AC9567862a70d7b000488e8ba80bc19787/Messages/MMebd9e089637c2c740608199af762fc19/Media/ME49a13b9e0732d78b84fe81d6c3c5a3f2"

Manually open the image on broswer automatically converts the https address to below:

url2 = "https://s3-external-1.amazonaws.com/media.twiliocdn.com/AC9567862a70d7b000488e8ba80bc19787/f28ad1174d0871048be68207a88d5cea"

```
from skimage import io
img = io.imread(url1) # < ---- error here
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
```

I'm trying to read the image from the url1 and perform OCR on the image.
(That is to read the image directly from (url1) without the need to open it on broswer and use the alternate address)

However, io.imread(url1) gives the error "urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden".

io.imread(url2) does not return any error.

Is there any way to read the image directly from url1 ?

Comment: Use browser integrated web developer tools to see the network requests. You may need special cookies or other headers to be able to download the image. Also make sure your python script uses a forged user agent string (e.g. the one from your web bowser).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code in the second line as skimage.io.imread() takes URL as a string input.

```
img = io.imread(String(URL))
```

Also you can use cv2 module instead.

```
# importing OpenCV(cv2) module
import cv2

img = cv2.imread(URL)

# Output img with window name as 'image'
cv2.imshow('image', img)
```

Comment: Hi, this is not really what i'm looking for I have edited the question to be more specific.

Comment: Hey, I think there must be an error in your API or you may shift to cv2 module instead of  skimage.

Comment: Hi I have tried cv2 as well is not working :(

Comment: Did you used `Request` from `urllib.request` in your API?

Comment: ur answer only works for url2, url1 is not working